# Presto : No factory for connector 'mysql'

Tags: java, mysql, presto

I am doing

`$ ./launcher run`

Below Error message is get generate

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No factory for connector 'mysql'. Available factories: [memory, kudu, blackhole, kinesis, redis, accumulo, gsheets, raptor-legacy, elasticsearch, jmx, postgresql, redshift, sqlserver, localfile, tpch, iceberg, bigquery, memsql, prometheus, mongodb, example-http, pinot, tpcds, oracle, phoenix, system, cassandra, kafka, atop, hive-hadoop2, presto-thrift]
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:441)
at io.prestosql.connector.ConnectorManager.createCatalog(ConnectorManager.java:185)
at io.prestosql.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalog(StaticCatalogStore.java:88)
at io.prestosql.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalogs(StaticCatalogStore.java:68)
at io.prestosql.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:117)
at io.prestosql.server.Server.lambda$start$0(Server.java:72)
at io.prestosql.$gen.Presto_336____20200622_041142_1.run(Unknown Source)
at io.prestosql.server.Server.start(Server.java:72)
at io.prestosql.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:39)
```

here is my 'mysql.properties' file

```
connector.name=mysql
connection-url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
connection-user=root
connection-password=onkar@77
```

Can any one please help.. please

Comment: I have structure as etc/catalog/mysql.properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mysql` plugin is definitely part of Presto 336, the version you are using.

I would assume the `<presto-install-dir>/plugin/mysql` directory got removed somehow on local installation.

Comment: You are right .. I am just adding that plugin only .. and it worked ... Thank for the help ...

Comment: but now its showing .. Plugin 'mysql' is not loaded.   now what?

Comment: `Plugin 'mysql' is not loaded` -- i do not think Presto produces this message. BTW for troubleshootings like that it's often more convenient to use `#troubleshooting` on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html). That feels a bit beyond SO scope.

Comment: same thing. I actually deleted a folder in data path that was symlink to plugin folder. Added the plugins and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "datasource.driver" to your 'mysql.properties' file.

Comment: datasource.driver=java.sql.Driver

Like this?

Comment: You can read more at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of trailing whitespaces in mysql.properties file. I had a similar issue while working with Kafka connector (No factory for connector kafka) and realized that trailing whitespaces were causing the problem. After removing the whitespaces in kafka.properties I got it working.